# Dbcontext IDbset properties are null when injected in ServiceStack IoC

Tags: c#, entity-framework, servicestack, ioc-container, dbcontext

I have registered my DbContext with the standard container in ServiceStack, the DbContext is injected into the service but strangely the `IDbSet` property is `null`, all the other properties are as expected.

If I new up the DbContext in the Service constructor the `IDbSet` property is instantiated as you would expect, just to prove the config for EF has been setup correctly. All the other registered services are injected correctly without this strange behaviour this way too.

What am I missing?

```
public class AppHost : AppHostBase
{
    public override void Configure(Container container)
    {
        container.AddScoped<IDbContext, MyDataContext>();
        // Other registrations here omitted for brevity.
    }
}

public interface IDbContext : IDisposable
{
    IDbSet<MyEntity> MyEntity { get; set; }

    DbChangeTracker ChangeTracker { get; }
    DbContextConfiguration Configuration { get; }
    Database Database { get; }

    int SaveChanges();
    Task<int> SaveChangesAsync();
    Task<int> SaveChangesAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken);

    DbEntityEntry<T> Entry<T>(T entity) where T : class;
}
```

Comment: Do you use an alternative (i.e. non-parameter-less) constructor when "newing-up" `MyDataContext`?

Comment: I just ignore the injected object and set the field like so `_dbcontext = new MyDataContext()` in the constructor so the signature doesn't change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have fixed this by changing the registration like so;

`container.Register<IDbContext>(i => new MyDataContext()).ReusedWithin(ReuseScope.Request);`

My original registration `container.AddScoped<IDbContext, MyDataContext>();` is shorthand for an autowired registration type; `container.RegisterAutoWiredAs<MyDataContext,IDbContext>().ReusedWithin(ReuseScope.Request);`

I wonder if the Func container is trying to resolve the iDbSet Properties when using AutoWired. Which would explain why they end up null.